# Editing values in a nested dictionary using .Items property with variable keys

Tags: json, vba, dictionary, ms-access

I have a nested dictionary created using the VBA-JSON library. For the moment at least it is a dictionary with an arbitrary number of subdictionaries and items in an arbitrary organization, no collections or other objects.
Below is a sample of the JSON I'm working with.

```
{
  "Product": {
    "Name": "Delta 14in Bandsaw",
    "Model#": "258-40",
    "Catalog#": "10XXXX",
    "Dimensions": {
      "DimMM": {
        "Height": "1500",
        "Width": "400",
        "Depth": "300"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to be able to access the value of each member in the dictionary and subdictionaries and update it individually. I figured the .Item property of Dictionaries would work for this.

```
dict("Product")("Dimensions")("DimMM").item("Height") = "1500"
```

```
path = "Product"
itemPath = "Name"
dict(path).item(itemPath) = "Delta 14in Bandsaw"
```

Both of the examples above work great, however I can't find a way to use a variable for the entire dictionary path when there is an arbitrary number of nested dictionaries

```
a = "Product"
b = "Dimensions"
c = "DimMM"
d = "Height"

Parsed(a)(b)(c).item(d) = "1500"
```

The above also works, but doesn't help me much when I need to construct this path on the fly for an arbitrary depth.

I initially thought that I could construct a string to use as the path, something like below (there are some syntax issues I know, my actual approach to this involved Join and constants to represent double quotes)

```
pString = "("Product")("Dimensions")("DimMM")"
itemPath = "Height"
dict(pString).item(itemPath) = "1500"
```

No version of the string approach worked, I get Error 424: Object Required. I quickly realized that the string approach wouldn't work as it is looking for an object name and ("Product")("Dimensions")("DimMM") is three object names as a string, not one.

I feel like I am missing something very obvious here, how can I construct the object name to input to the .Item property on the fly? Am I approaching this poorly in general? Are there other more straightforward methods of updating dictionary members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim json As Object
    
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Range("A1").Value)
    
    Debug.Print JsonValue(json, "Product/Name")                     '>> Delta 14in Bandsaw
    Debug.Print JsonValue(json, "Product/Dimensions/DimMM/Height")  '>> 1500
    JsonValue json, "Product/Dimensions/DimMM/Height", 1600         'set new value
    Debug.Print JsonValue(json, "Product/Dimensions/DimMM/Height")  '>> 1600
    
End Sub

'read/set the value of a key at the end of a json path
Function JsonValue(json, path As String, Optional v = Empty)
    Dim obj As Object, el As String, arr, i As Long
    Set obj = json
    arr = Split(path, "/") 'split path to an array
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        Set obj = obj(arr(i)) 'assign next object in path
    Next i
    JsonValue = obj(arr(UBound(arr))) 'return current value (key is last item in array)
    If Not IsEmpty(v) Then obj(arr(UBound(arr))) = v 'optionally update the value if a new value was passed
End Function
```

(only tested with nested dictionaries - might need adjustments if you also need to deal with collections/arrays)

Comment: Thank you for the swift and succinct answer. I think this solution will work perfectly. I _mostly_ understand what is going on here. Could you clarify for me what is happening in the For loop? What about the structure or composition of the json dictionary changes after the loop? Re: collections, I've abandoned (for now at least) trying to make collections within dictionaries play nice with any method of handling the actual data, nested dictionaries seem to fully cover my use case right now anyway.

Comment: The loop just shifts obj down the tree in the json structure until you get to the dictionary which contains the key you want to read or set.

Comment: Ah right so it is 'walking' through the structure of the dictionary in a similar sense to how you loop through a dictionary to read the values? So the structure of  `JsonValue = obj(arr(Ubound(arr)))` is effectively `JsonValue = "DimMM"("Height")`? I was also wondering how the original `json` object gets updated when it isn't called again in the function, but now I realize that if `obj` represents the dictionary `DimMM` then this just updates the nested dictionary without touching the higher levels, is this correct? That really clarifies nested objects for me if so. Thanks again!

Comment: That's about it, yes.  Good to hear you found it useful.